# How to add the roman numbers in decimal with a MIPS code?

Tags: assembly, mips, decode, mips32, roman-numerals

So, I did pretty well on my last home assignment, where I also had to implement a program as a task in MIPS-assembly. I understood the concept and the logic of it with a little help. But still, MIPS is very new to me, and I am still learning and hoping to improve my skills in coding with MIPS.

But this time, I am completely confused. The whole logic of the task is just completely weird and confusing. And I can't understand the error messages.

The task is to implement a Roman number decoder, which sounds pretty easy at first. But I have to use the given registers, and I am not allowed to change above the label\function `roman.`

```
.data

str_input: .asciiz "numeral: "
str_return_value: .asciiz "\nReturn value: "
romdigit_table: .word 0, 0, 0, 100, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 50, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

.text

.eqv SYS_PUTSTR 4
.eqv SYS_PUTCHAR 11
.eqv SYS_PUTINT 1
.eqv SYS_EXIT 10

main:
    # roman numeral is output:
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_input
    syscall

    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, test_numeral
    syscall
    
    li $v0, SYS_PUTSTR
    la $a0, str_return_value
    syscall

    move $v0, $zero
    # calling the function roman:
    la $a0, test_numeral
    jal roman
    
    # return value is output:
    move $a0, $v0
    li $v0, SYS_PUTINT
    syscall

    # end of program execution:
    li $v0, SYS_EXIT
    syscall
    
    # help function: int romdigit(char digit);
romdigit:
    move $v0, $zero
    andi $t0, $a0, 0xE0
    addi $t1, $zero, 0x40
    beq $t0, $t1, _romdigit_not_null
    addi $t1, $zero, 0x60
    beq $t0, $t1, _romdigit_not_null
    jr $ra
_romdigit_not_null:
    andi $t0, $a0, 0x1F
    sll $t0, $t0, 2
    la $t1, romdigit_table
    add $t1, $t1, $t0
    lw $v0, 0($t1)
    jr $ra


.data

test_numeral: .asciiz "DCCXLVI"

.text

roman:


    li $t0, 0 # result
    
    li $t1, 0 # Index in 'test_numeral'
    
    
roman_decoder:

    la $a0, test_numeral # reseting $a0
    
    add $a0, $t1, $a0 # adding the new index to the pointer $a0

    lb $t2, 0($a0) # first number in 'test_numeral'
    
    lb $t3, 1($a0) # second number in 'test_numeral'
    
    beqz $t3, exit # exit if zero is reached
    
    lb $a0, 0($a0) # given help function 'romdigit' needs $a0 as the argument
    
    bgt $t3, $t2, subtract # if $t3 > $t2 subtract $t2 from result
    
    j add
    
    
subtract: # subtract $t2 from the result

    jal romdigit # calling 'romdigit'
    
    sub $t0, $t0, $v0 # in $v0 is the encrypted decimal number
    
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    
    j roman_decoder

add: # add $t2 to the result

    jal romdigit # calling 'romdigit'
    
    add $t0, $t0, $v0 # in $v0 is the encrypted decimal number
    
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    
    j roman_decoder

exit:
    
    jr $ra
```

The logic behind my code is simple. Iterate through `test_numeral` till `\0`; read the roman number and decode it with `romdigit`; add the value stored in `$v0` to the result register.

I am still pretty confused that I have to use `$a0` as the pointer to `test_numeral` and as the  holder of the current roman number to be used in `romdigit`.

I think this code could work in theory but i wasn't able to get it run properly. I am really in despair.

I mean there are many ways to actually solve this problem. This was the easiest one I could think of. But I am always getting an "address out of range" error and I dont understand why....

I thought it would make sense to have a counter for the index `$t1`, which is increased by one every time a Roman number is read, and after I've used `$a0` in romdigit, to add `$t1` back to `$a0` to get to the new index in `test_numeral` . But this didn't work so well, and I have no clue how to do it another way.

I would appreciate any hints on this one. Thank you guys in advance!

I was busy so I couldn`t really work on the code anymore.

But I think I have a working code now. The only issue is that it wont stop:

```
.data

test_numeral: .asciiz "DCCXLVI"

.text

roman:

    move $t3, $a0 
    
    li $t2, 0 
    
    li $t4, 0 

roman_decoder:

    move $t4, $v0
    
    lb $a0, 0($t3)
    
    beqz $a0, exit
    
    jal romdigit
    
    bgt $v0, $t4, subtract
    
    add $t2, $t2, $v0
    
    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    
    j roman_decoder
    
subtract:

    sub $t2, $t2, $t4
    
    sub $t2, $t2, $t4
    
    add $t2, $t2, $v0
    
    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    
    j roman_decoder
    
exit:

    move $v0, $t2
    
    jr $ra
```

When `$a0` is zero, the code jumps to `exit`. Moves `$t2` in `$v0` and should end because I'm saying `jr $ra`, so it should jump back to main to end the program right? What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `bgt $t3, $t2, subtract` is already wrong since you are comparing the roman letter not the value.

Comment: If you want help with an error message, cite the error message in its entirety, and point out what instruction is getting that error.  Errors like that are usually type mismatches, such as dereferencing a non-pointer value, i.e. dereferencing a character, which is a logic error.  One good way to debug this is to compare with a known to be working or tested to be working algorithm written in C or a language you know well.  You don't have to think in assembly to make an algorithm.  Debugging a broken algorithm in assembly is hard, but having a working algorithm in another language can help.

Comment: I have found a new way to write the code, i think it should work. But the program won't stop now...

Comment: @checkchecker If you fixed the problem in a way that's useful to future visitors, please [post a self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) explaining how you did it, with a complete, runnable example. Then, if you have a new question/problem, ask that separately. Or, since nobody has responded to this question, you might want to fix your original problem and [edit] the post to ask the new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be, that the romdigit function itself uses the jr callback to continue in roman_decoder. In doing this, it also changes the value of the $ra register, so the exit function calls the romand_decoder again instead of the main function. Try to store the value of $ra in an extra register before calling romdigit and in the exit function load the value back to the $ra register before using the callback

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).